# Ionic framework: Error after updating ionic version to 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I’ve this issue after updating ionic version. I cant even start my ionic project. Is there anyone who can help me through this. Thank you. since I cant use ionic info, I just list npm to show what I've so far.

```
$ npm list -g --depth=0

/Users/phyopwintthu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/lib

├── cordova@8.0.0

├── hoek@5.0.4

├── ionic@4.1.2

├── npm@6.4.1

├── socks@2.2.1

└── ws@3.3.2
```

> ```
> > $ ionic events.js:167
> >       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> >       ^
> > 
> > TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of
> > type string or Buffer. Received type object
> >     at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:258:10)
> >     at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:292:21)
> >     at process.<anonymous> (/Users/phyopwintthu/.nvm/versions/node/v10.10.0/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:9:63)
> >     at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
> >     at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:105:20)
> >     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34) Emitted 'error' event at:
> >     at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:261:12)
> >     at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:292:21)
> >     [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
> >     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)
> ```

Comment: Have a look at this issue which looks like your problem: https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/213

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not used fcm tho. I can't even start new ionic project in fact since "ionic" keyword throws this error to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

```
npm uninstall -g ionic@4
```

and later

```
npm install -g ionic@3
```

and also if you want to change your ionic version, you can check [Upgrade Link](https://moduscreate.com/blog/upgrading-an-ionic-3-application-to-ionic-4/)